# Get a member URL action with ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, activeresource

I have a route in my application that is like this:

```
/deployments/:id/logs.json
```

It is used to retrieve logs for a specific deployment. On my client code, based in *ActiveResource* I have this:

```
logs = Deployment.find(deployment.id).get(:logs, opts)
```

Where opts is some parameters that I send via query string.

The problem with this code is that it breaks the request in two. The `Deployment#find` method requests:

```
GET /deployments/:id.json
```

And then, if this is found, a second request is sent:

```
GET /deployments/:id/logs.json
```

Is it possible to skip the first query altogether using Rails 3 on the server and ActiveResource (current requirements for activeresource is >= 2.3.5 but I am fine with bumping it if needed)?

**UPDATE**: I think it works if I change:

```
logs = Deployment.find(deployment.id).get(:logs, opts)
```

to

```
logs = Deployment.new(:id => deployment.id).get(:logs, opts)
```

Any comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it works if I change:

```
logs = Deployment.find(deployment.id).get(:logs, opts)
```

to

```
logs = Deployment.new(:id => deployment.id).get(:logs, opts)
```